# Characterizing superposition of two renewal processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, renewal-processes

This is a follow-up question of "[When superposition of two renewal processes is another renewal process?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536488/when-superposition-of-two-renewal-processes-is-another-renewal-process)".

> How can we characterize the superposition of two renewal processes?

The superposition of two independent renewal processes is not generally a renewal process, but it can be described within a larger class of processes called the Markov-renewal processes. How can we characterize the superposition of them according to the parameters of each of the renewal processes?

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the two component renewal processes have the same interrenewal distribution $F$, the interarrival distribution of the superimposed process has density
$$g(x) = -\frac1\mu\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\left[\bar F(x)\int_x^\infty\bar F(u)\ \mathsf d u\right], $$
as derived in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312167/superposition-of-renewal-processes-variance-of-lifetimes/1544183). Here $\bar F=1-F$ is the survival function of the component interrenewal times and $\mu$ is the mean component interrenewal time. We can further simplify the above to $$\frac1\mu\left(\bar F(x)^2 + f(x)\int_x^\infty \bar F(u)\ \mathsf d u  \right). $$  For example, if the component renewal processes have $U(0,1)$ interrenewal times, I computed the density of the interarrival times in the superimposed process to be $$g(x) = 3(1-x)^2\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(x). $$

Comment: thanks a lot for your that. How about the general case where  inter-renewal distributions are not identical?